# How do you create a square UIView with borders at each corner?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uikit

How can I hardcode something like the attached image? I'm trying to build a QR code scanner UI and this would be very beneficial.

Also, not as important, but how could I achieve the dark background around this square so only the square is transparent?

[image: Square with border at each corner]

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a combination of `CAShapeLayer`s and `UIBezierPath`s

To "cut a hole" in a layer:

- create a "full bounds" bezier path
- create an inset rounded-rect bezier path
- append the rounded-rect path to the full path
- set `.fillRule = .evenOdd`

Then for the "white corners":

- create a new bezier path
- `move` to a "leg" starting point
- `addLine` to the corner-arc starting point
- `addArc`
- `addLine` for "leg" extension
- repeat for each corner

Here's an example class:

```
@IBDesignable
class BorderedCutoutView: UIView {
    
    @IBInspectable
    var bkgColor: UIColor = .systemBlue { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var brdColor: UIColor = .white { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var brdWidth: CGFloat = 1 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var legLength: CGFloat = 1 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var radius: CGFloat = 20 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var horizInset: CGFloat = 40.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    @IBInspectable
    var vertInset: CGFloat = 60.0 { didSet { setNeedsLayout() } }
    
    private let cutoutLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    private let borderLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        commonInit()
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
        commonInit()
    }
    
    override func prepareForInterfaceBuilder() {
        super.prepareForInterfaceBuilder()
        backgroundColor = .clear
    }
    private func commonInit() -> Void {
        backgroundColor = .clear
        layer.addSublayer(cutoutLayer)
        layer.addSublayer(borderLayer)
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        let path = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds)
        let cp = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: bounds.insetBy(dx: horizInset, dy: vertInset), cornerRadius: radius)
        path.append(cp)
        path.usesEvenOddFillRule = true
        
        cutoutLayer.path = path.cgPath
        cutoutLayer.fillRule = .evenOdd
        cutoutLayer.fillColor = bkgColor.cgColor
        
        // corners path
        let insetRect = bounds.insetBy(dx: horizInset, dy: vertInset)
        let cornersPath = UIBezierPath()
        
        var pt1: CGPoint = .zero
        var pt2: CGPoint = .zero
        var curCenter: CGPoint = .zero
        
        // top-left
        pt1.x = insetRect.minX
        pt1.y = insetRect.minY + radius + legLength
        
        pt2 = pt1
        pt2.y -= legLength
        
        cornersPath.move(to: pt1)
        cornersPath.addLine(to: pt2)
        
        pt1 = cornersPath.currentPoint
        
        curCenter = pt1
        curCenter.x += radius
        
        cornersPath.addArc(withCenter: curCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: .pi * 1.0, endAngle: .pi * 1.5, clockwise: true)
        
        pt1 = cornersPath.currentPoint
        pt2 = pt1
        pt2.x += legLength
        
        cornersPath.addLine(to: pt2)
        
        // top-right
        pt1.x = insetRect.maxX - (radius + legLength)
        pt1.y = insetRect.minY
        
        pt2 = pt1
        pt2.x += legLength
        
        cornersPath.move(to: pt1)
        cornersPath.addLine(to: pt2)
        
        pt1 = cornersPath.currentPoint
        
        curCenter = pt1
        curCenter.y += radius
        
        cornersPath.addArc(withCenter: curCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: .pi * 1.5, endAngle: .pi * 2.0, clockwise: true)
        
        pt1 = cornersPath.currentPoint
        pt2 = pt1
        pt2.y += legLength
        
        cornersPath.addLine(to: pt2)
        
        // bottom-right
        pt1.x = insetRect.maxX
        pt1.y = insetRect.maxY - (radius + legLength)
        
        pt2 = pt1
        pt2.y += legLength
        
        cornersPath.move(to: pt1)
        cornersPath.addLine(to: pt2)
        
        pt1 = cornersPath.currentPoint
        
        curCenter = pt1
        curCenter.x -= radius
        
        cornersPath.addArc(withCenter: curCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: .pi * 0.0, endAngle: .pi * 0.5, clockwise: true)
        
        pt1 = cornersPath.currentPoint
        pt2 = pt1
        pt2.x -= legLength
        
        cornersPath.addLine(to: pt2)
        
        // bottom-left
        pt1.x = insetRect.minX + (radius + legLength)
        pt1.y = insetRect.maxY
        
        pt2 = pt1
        pt2.x -= legLength
        
        cornersPath.move(to: pt1)
        cornersPath.addLine(to: pt2)
        
        pt1 = cornersPath.currentPoint
        
        curCenter = pt1
        curCenter.y -= radius
        
        cornersPath.addArc(withCenter: curCenter, radius: radius, startAngle: .pi * 0.5, endAngle: .pi * 1.0, clockwise: true)
        
        pt1 = cornersPath.currentPoint
        pt2 = pt1
        pt2.y -= legLength
        
        cornersPath.addLine(to: pt2)
        
        borderLayer.path = cornersPath.cgPath
        borderLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        borderLayer.lineWidth = brdWidth
        borderLayer.strokeColor = brdColor.cgColor
        
    }
    
}
```

It's marked `@IBDesignable` with the necessary `@IBInspectable` properties so we can lay it out in Storyboard / Interface Builder if desired.

Here's an example of how it can look:

[image]

Using these properties (background color is Black with 40% opacity):

[image]